# Delay/defer document.write from an external script till after document ready

Tags: javascript, ads, document.write, deferred-execution

I have an external script which loads advertisements. The script being loaded includes calls to `document.write`. The problem is this delays the doc ready for the site.  I would like to delay showing this until after the doc ready.

Currently I just tried wrapping the function that loads the external content in a jquery doc ready, but the page blows up.  It goes to a all white screen with just the ad and some code showing.

Obviously this is because document.write is running after the page is loaded.  Does anyone know a way around this or how to delay loading of the external content till after doc ready?

Comment: The only way I know to do this is to make sure your ads load in one or more `<iframe>` elements on your page. Those are their own little worlds unto themselves, at least to some extent.

Comment: Yes that it what I switched to for the time being. Although I am worried the iframe may have disadvantages.

Comment: doing more research I came across this.  Has anyone used it?

http://jqueryad.web2ajax.fr/

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved for you:

[by the fine people behind Postscribe](https://github.com/krux/postscribe)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [hack where you override document.write and buffer the output](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=195112), then write it to a div in doc ready.

Comment: has anyone else used this?  Is there any working examples or other usage of similar techniques online?

Comment: this looks promising, doing more research I have found other uses of that, such as here.  http://jqueryad.web2ajax.fr/

Comment: These aren't exactly the same thing described above, but I found blog posts from John Resig (http://ejohn.org/blog/xhtml-documentwrite-and-adsense/) and Steve Souders (http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/12/15/controljs-part-3/) about overriding document.write, so I do think lots of people are doing it. I first heard about the technique at the Velocity conference.

Answer (score 0):

@jhanifen: My first thought was of the `defer` attribute, which I've used before specifically when I had issues with certain scripts in Internet Explorer that used `document.write`. I wasn't sure if it would work so well in the context of ads loaded from external sources so I did I search on SO for it and came across this question and accepted answer -- [Is it possible to load a javascript ad last on the page to prevent slow load times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454534/is-it-possible-to-load-a-javascript-ad-last-on-the-page-to-prevent-slow-load-time) -- which may prove to be / or help you towards getting your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work as well:

https://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture

> Utility to assist the Ajax loading of HTML containing script tags that use document.write