# Load ad after page loaded

Tags: javascript, load, ads

On my website I display some advertisements and it should be loaded like this:

```
<div id='ad'>
http://ad.affiliate.com/?id=12345
</div>
```

But when I use that script, the ad can slow down the loading time of the website. How can I load that script after the page has loaded? I tried this but that doesn't work.

```
<div id='ad'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#ad").load("http://ad.affiliate.com/?id=12345");
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can i use this samples for google adsense ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try use the **defer** attribute.
Maybe this could help you: [Is it possible to load a javascript ad last on the page to prevent slow load times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454534/is-it-possible-to-load-a-javascript-ad-last-on-the-page-to-prevent-slow-load-tim)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **$(document).ready()**, you can use **$(window).load()**

```
<div id='ad'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
            $("#ad").load("http://ad.affiliate.com/?id=12345");
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Hope this works.

Muhammad...

Answer (score -1):

Or maybe this thing can do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#ad").load("http://ad.affiliate.com/?id=12345");
    }, 0);
});
```